# Streaming a local mpeg-ts file to udp using gstreamer

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

I need to broadcast a mpeg-ts video file using gstreamer without transcoding it. The video is encoded in: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (h264)

I've tried to stream with

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=my_video.ts ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=49444
```

and play with

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc caps=" application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264,payload=(int)96,ssrc=(uint)2674837201,clock-base=(uint)2959668548,seqnum-base=(uint)14300" port=49444 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

but the video I have on the receiver's side is corrupted (but it's still a little bit similar to the original video):

[image]

And there are a lot of warnings in the receiver's console:

```
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0: Could not decode stream.
Additional debug info:
gstrtph264depay.c(1205): gst_rtp_h264_depay_process (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0:
Undefined packet type
```

What am I doing wrong? I guess the problem is in the `caps` parameter of `udpsrc` element, because I've just copy-pasted it from some example on the web. If this is the problem, how can I find out a proper value for the `caps` parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot go directly from ts file to h264parse, you need to first demux the ts stream - this is done with tsdemux.

This is the magic pipe:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=dummy_h264.ts ! tsparse set-timestamps=true ! video/mpegts ! tsdemux ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse disable-passthrough=true ! rtph264pay ! udpsink -v host=127.0.0.1 port=9999
```

Without tsparse set-timestamp it may not work because the timestamping information may not be present in your ts file - you have to check if there is proper PCR frames - maybe with some mpeg ts analyser.

And debug output - you take the caps from line talking about udpsink:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/MpegTSParse2:mpegtsparse2-0.GstPad:src: caps = "video/mpegts\,\ systemstream\=\(boolean\)true\,\ packetsize\=\(int\)188"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = "video/mpegts\,\ systemstream\=\(boolean\)true\,\ packetsize\=\(int\)188"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0.GstPad:sink: caps = "video/mpegts\,\ systemstream\=\(boolean\)true\,\ packetsize\=\(int\)188"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = "video/mpegts\,\ systemstream\=\(boolean\)true\,\ packetsize\=\(int\)188"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter2: caps = video/x-h264
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter2.GstPad:src: caps = "video/x-h264\,\ stream-format\=\(string\)byte-stream\,\ alignment\=\(string\)nal"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = "video/x-h264\,\ stream-format\=\(string\)byte-stream\,\ alignment\=\(string\)nal"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter2.GstPad:sink: caps = "video/x-h264\,\ stream-format\=\(string\)byte-stream\,\ alignment\=\(string\)nal"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = "video/x-h264\,\ stream-format\=\(string\)avc\,\ alignment\=\(string\)au\,\ pixel-aspect-ratio\=\(fraction\)1/1\,\ width\=\(int\)320\,\ height\=\(int\)240\,\ framerate\=\(fraction\)30/1\,\ parsed\=\(boolean\)true\,\ profile\=\(string\)high\,\ level\=\(string\)2\,\ codec_data\=\(buffer\)01640014ffe1001967640014acd94141fb0110000003001000000303c8f142996001000568ebecb22c"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:src: caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H264\,\ packetization-mode\=\(string\)1\,\ profile-level-id\=\(string\)640014\,\ sprop-parameter-sets\=\(string\)\"Z2QAFKzZQUH7ARAAAAMAEAAAAwPI8UKZYA\\\=\\\=\\\,aOvssiw\\\=\"\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)3030226714\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)3947899684\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)32736"
------------TAKE THIS ONE:--------------
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H264\,\ packetization-mode\=\(string\)1\,\ profile-level-id\=\(string\)640014\,\ sprop-parameter-sets\=\(string\)\"Z2QAFKzZQUH7ARAAAAMAEAAAAwPI8UKZYA\\\=\\\=\\\,aOvssiw\\\=\"\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)3030226714\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)3947899684\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)32736"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0.GstPad:sink: caps = "video/x-h264\,\ stream-format\=\(string\)avc\,\ alignment\=\(string\)au\,\ pixel-aspect-ratio\=\(fraction\)1/1\,\ width\=\(int\)320\,\ height\=\(int\)240\,\ framerate\=\(fraction\)30/1\,\ parsed\=\(boolean\)true\,\ profile\=\(string\)high\,\ level\=\(string\)2\,\ codec_data\=\(buffer\)01640014ffe1001967640014acd94141fb0110000003001000000303c8f142996001000568ebecb22c"
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0: timestamp = 3947910934
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0: seqnum = 32736
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Execution ended after 0:00:03.631302966
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Then play it like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=9999 ! application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\... ! queue ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! glimagesink
```

Note that you do not have to add " around caps its already escaped..

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your magic pipe works fine!

However I had some glitches on received video until I added a `queue` element in the player's pipeline

Comment: @Paboka ok I edited answer.. its good to have queues everywhere where it makes sense.. but I think decodebin already uses some queues internally..

Comment: when I'm running this and playing the video, it's not running smooth. how do you fix that?